# Is it practical to have a model which uses no Qt classes but to use a Qt view?

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

Assume that I have a simulation (the "model") which at the moment runs in the console and doesn't have any Qt specific code. Lets pretend it has a ball class

```
struct Ball
{
     unsigned int unique_id;
     float x;
     float y;
};
```

Using QGraphicsScene with QGraphicsView and either QGraphicsItem or QGraphicsPolygonItem I can also draw shapes (a circle say) in any given position on the scene using Qt.

Ideally I would like to continue using Qt for displaying the balls (as it is easy to use in that regard) but not intertwine Qt with my model (so that I can easily swap parts of the model in and out). Is there a "nice" way to associate the balls in my model with the QGraphicsItems that I can draw on the screen? If not what is the correct way to do this in Qt?

Answer (score 1):

You can store [arbitrary data](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setData) on each `QGraphicsItem`.  One reasonable choice is to store a pointer to the corresponding `Ball` object.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, so in this scheme after the model updates you would then iterate through all the QGraphicsItems get their ball and update their position and any other properties is that correct? Also what is the advantage of using a QVariant over storing a Ball pointer directly. Thanks!

Comment: @CanISleepYet: Sure: the “rendering” loop might be in an event handler.  As for storing `Ball*`, obviously that type can’t appear in the `QGraphicsItem` interface.  Qt uses `QVariant` rather than providing completely generic type erasure like `std::any` does.